# How can I get XMLStarlet to extract multiple developer roles when parsing pom.xml?

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, pom.xml, xmlstarlet

I am parsing hundreds of poms **with a bash script** in a weird hierarchy to extract an overview of all the projects into a single report (the kind of thing that maven-info-projects:project-team can't do in one go). For undisclosed reasons I don't want to mess with a parent pom or try and configure maven-info-projects sections.

I am using [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) because it is installed, and [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) is not.

Given a pom.xml extract that contains:

```
<developer>
   <id>devId</id>
   <name>Developer Name</name>
   <email>dev@nowhere.com</email>
   <roles>
      <role>Project manager</role>
      <role>Developer</role>
   </roles>
</developer>
```

How can I extract all developer info, including the multiple roles, with a single call to [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)?

At the moment, I can extract the bulk of my information with:

```
# Developers
locate_section_values $pom_file_name "/x:project/x:developers/x:developer" \
    "concat( \
        x:id, '|', x:name, '|', x:email, '|', x:roles, '|', \
        x:organization, '|', x:organizationUrl, '|', x:timezone
     )"
```

where

```
function locate_section_values(){
  local xml_file=$1
  local section=$2
  local value_table=$3

  OLD_IFS=$IFS
  IFS=$'\n'
  xml_values=()
  xml_values=(`xmlstarlet sel -B -N x="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" -t -m "$section" -v "$value_table" -nl $xml_file`)
  IFS=$OLD_IFS
}
```

I then split the results:

```
  for developer in ${xml_values[@]}; do
    IFS='|' 
    set $developer # split into $1, $2, etc using | as seperator
    #echo "id:${1}, name:${2}, roles:${4}"

    if [ -n "${1}" ]; then # id
      developer_id=${1}
      developer_ids+=( $developer_id )
    fi
    ...
```

The problem is, a developer with multiple roles gets their roles concatenated:

```
 Project managerDeveloper
```

Is there a way to tell the original call to xmlstarlet to combine multiple roles into, for example, a comma-seperated list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following gives approximately what you want, but you'll have to change the interface to `locate_section_values`:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -B -N x="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" \
   -t -m "/x:project/x:developers/x:developer" -v "x:id" -o "|" \
   -v "x:name" -o "|" -v "x:email" -o "|" \
   -m "x:roles/x:role" -v "." -o "," -b -o "|" \
   -v "x:organization" -o "|" -v "x:organizationUrl" -o "|" \
   -v "x:timezone" --nl 
  $pom_file_name
```

That produces roles as a comma *terminated* list because it's easier to code.

---

`locate_section_values` sans `eval`:

```
function locate_section_values() {
    local xml_file=$1 # $local_project_dir/$fixed_name/pom.xml
    local section=$2 #/x:project/x:modules/x:module
    local value_table=("${@:3}")

    OLD_IFS=$IFS
    IFS=$'\n'
    xml_values=($(xmlstarlet sel -B -N x=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 \
        -t -m "$section" "${value_table[@]}" --nl "$xml_file"))
    IFS=$OLD_IFS
}
```

call:

```
locate_section_values "$pom_file_name" '/x:project/x:developers/x:developer' \
      -v 'x:id' -o '|' -v 'x:name' -o '|' -v 'x:email' -o '|' \
      -m 'x:roles/x:role' -v '.' -o ', ' -b -o '|' \
      -v 'x:organization' -o '|' -v 'x:organizationUrl' -o '|' \
      -v 'x:timezone'
```

loop over developers and extract fields:

```
for developer in "${xml_values[@]}"; do
    # get | separated fields
    IFS='|' read id name email roles org orgUrl timezone <<<"$developer"

    if [ -n "$roles" ]; then # roles
        developer_roles_csv=${roles%, } # strip trailing comma
    fi

    echo "$name ($id) has roles: $developer_roles_csv."

done # developer
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer provided by [@npostavs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14573548/1491089), I have the following which works:

```
function locate_section_values(){
  local xml_file=$1 # $local_project_dir/$fixed_name/pom.xml
  local section=$2 #/x:project/x:modules/x:module
  local value_table=${@:3}

  OLD_IFS=$IFS
  IFS=$'\n'
  xml_values=()
  xml_cmd="xmlstarlet sel -B -N x=\"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0\" \
      -t -m \"$section\" $value_table -nl $xml_file"
  xml_values=(`eval $xml_cmd`)
  IFS=$OLD_IFS
}
```

Which parses the developers if I call it like this:

```
  # Developers
  locate_section_values $pom_file_name "/x:project/x:developers/x:developer" \
      -v \"x:id\" -o \"\|\" -v \"x:name\" -o \"\|\" -v \"x:email\" -o \"\|\" \
      -m \"x:roles/x:role\" -v \".\" -o \", \" -b -o \"\|\" \
      -v \"x:organization\" -o \"\|\" -v \"x:organizationUrl\" -o \"\|\" \
      -v \"x:timezone\"
```

I can easily remove the trailing "comma and space" with "developer_roles_csv=${4%??}":

```
  OLD_IFS=$IFS
  IFS=$'\n'
  for developer in ${xml_values[@]}; do
    IFS='|' 
    set $developer # split into $1, $2, etc using | as seperator

    ....

    if [ -n "${4}" ]; then # roles
      developer_roles_csv=${4%??} # strip trailing comma
      .....
    fi

    ....

  done # developer
  IFS=$OLD_IFS
```

Comment: I think defining `value_table` as an array would let you avoid the eval and extra layer of quoting.

Comment: Also: `--nl` or `-n` is correct. `-nl` appears to accepted but I would consider that a bug.

Comment: @npostavs I'd be interested in seeing your re-implementation of `locate_section_values` using `value_table` as an array. I really struggled to get the solution to work (I had to use `eval`).

Comment: I added `locate_section_values` to my answer. The main thing you were missing is that double quoting an array (`"${array[@]}"`) prevents word re-splitting.

Comment: Brilliant! Neater, easier to read and hence more maintainable. And it does the job. Thanks!