# Adding a "project health" attribute to pom.xml for 3rd party dependency monitoring

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I am working with an organisation that has a large set of projects, all managed by maven (with some custom plugins) and all with a pom.xml.

While most of the projects are developed internally, some of the projects are external (e.g. open source) projects that come with their own POM.

I've been tasked with adding some tags to these external project POMs that can be used by an internal project reporting tool (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565330/)) to report on these "external" projects, that provides a URL to the project's website and a short statement on the "health" of the project (e.g. mailing list is active, no signs that the project is about to die).

For the project's URL, I expect that I can use the URL provided in the [Organization](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Organization) section.

Can I just add "projectHealth" and "status" tags to the organization section? e.g.

```
  <organization>
    <name>Codehaus Mojo</name>
    <url>http://mojo.codehaus.org</url>

    <status>external</status>
    <projectHealth>
      Mailing list at http://archive.codehaus.org/lists/org.codehaus.mojo.dev is 404.
      Mailing list at http://markmail.org/list/org.codehaus.mojo.dev is active.
      Project seems active.
    </projectHealth>

  </organization>
```

Then I can detect "external" projects via the "status" tag and publish the health statement in my report.

I mean, this won't break any other plugin, will it?

Or is there an existing protocol that is preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pom.xml tags and structure are defined by an xsd (you can see it on top of every pom.xml : `xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd`)

This xsd is very strict and don't give you the freedom to add tags here and there without breaking something.

The strategy used by standard project reporting plugins to allow customization of reports is to use a bundle file (i.e. not the pom.xml) (example [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/mailing-list-mojo.html#customBundle)). So I suggest you to do the same for your internal reporting tool.

An alternative could be to put information inside the project `description` tag in a format that your tool is able to parse. I mean something like this

```
<description>
    STATUS:external
    MAILING LIST: http://archive.codehaus.org/lists/org.codehaus.mojo.dev
    MAILING LIST: http://markmail.org/list/org.codehaus.mojo.dev
    COMMENT: Project seems active
</description>
```

Unfortunately, it will pollute existing description and you won't have any static validation on that content.

Comment: Hmm.. thanks for this. If I have to use another "parent" tag, can't I move the "status" and "projectHealth" into `<properties>`? I would prefer not to use `<description>`.

Comment: Using properties can be an option... but be careful with them since they are inherited.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I'll test and check if the results are what I expect.